# Google Drive API - Automated Queries Message

Tags: docker, google-drive-api, ghost-blog, google-cloud-run

I am using [this](https://github.com/robincsamuel/ghost-google-drive) Ghost plugin to store image data on Google Drive. Recently, images have stopped loading with this error page downloaded in place of the image:

[image: https://github.com/robincsamuel/ghost-google-drive]

The site is running in a containerized Ghost instance on Google Cloud Run, source [here](https://github.com/behoyh/ghost)

Do I need to open a support ticket somewhere to resolve this? Site in question is [here](https://westmichigancopts.org)

EDIT: Here is the code used to access the saved content.

```
jwtClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        const drive = google.drive({
          version: API_VERSION,
          auth: jwtClient
        });
        drive.files.get(
          {
            fileId: id
          },
          function(err, response) {
            if (!err) {
              const file = response.data;
              const newReq = https
                .request(
                  file.downloadUrl + "&access_token=" + tokens.access_token,
                  function(newRes) {
                    // Modify google headers here to cache!
                    const headers = newRes.headers;
                    headers["content-disposition"] =
                      "attachment; filename=" + file.originalFilename;
                    headers["cache-control"] = "public, max-age=1209600";
                    delete headers["expires"];

                    res.writeHead(newRes.statusCode, headers);
                    // pipe the file
                    newRes.pipe(res);
                  }
                )
                .on("error", function(err) {
                  console.log(err);
                  res.statusCode = 500;
                  res.end();
                });
              req.pipe(newReq);
            } else {
              next(err);
            }
          }
        );
      });
```

Comment: Which kind of credentials is your code using to access Google Drive?

Comment: It’s a service account token

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not programming related SO cant tell you when or if you should send a support ticket to Google you should check google support pages yourself.

Comment: Using a service account is your problem. However, there are not enough details in your question on how you are creating the tokens, how you are impersonating, etc.

Comment: Updated question. It's a temporary JWT token created from service account access key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is related to `file.downloadUrl`. This field is not guaranteed to work and is not supposed to be used to download files.

The correct way to do this is to use the `webContentLink` property instead. You can look at [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive) for reference.

Comment: Now I'm getting a 503 error: https://westmichigancopts.org/content/images/1YkR2w_wsrYdNfrRV2fmlVb6WTiyMkLz5.png

Comment: Fixed the issue, PR here: https://github.com/robincsamuel/ghost-google-drive/pull/23